# Zebra ZD621 Printing with DF (Store Format) and XF (Recall Format)

Tags: zebra-printers, zpl, zpl-ii, zebra

Am printing blank labels when trying to use store format (`DF`) and recall format (`XF`) when printing to a Zebra printer. ZPL code was generated using Zebra Designer and print to file.

Code below for store format. If I send this to the printer I get a label that has "Test Label" with no additional text. Wanting to use FN1 to add variable text in the recall format.

```
CT~~CD,~CC^~CT~
^XA
^DFR:TEST.GRF
~TA050
~JSN
^LT0
^MNW
^MTT
^PON
^PMN
^LH0,0
^JMA
^PR4,4
~SD15
^JUS
^LRN
^CI27
^PA0,1,1,0
^XZ
^XA
^MMT
^PW830
^LL1218
^LS0
^FT187,793^A0B,23,23^FH\^CI28^FDTEST LABEL^FS^CI27
^FT408,743^A0B,52,53^FN1^FS
^PQ1,0,1,Y
^XZ
```

Code below for recall format. Result when sending this to the printer is a blank label.

```
^XA
^XFR:TEST.GRF
^FN1^FDTHIS IS A TEST LABEL^FS
^XZ
```

Comment: Your code for store format has two labels. Only the first one is stored, and you do all the printing in the second one.